# Adding string inside an XML Tag in Java?

Tags: java, xml, nsxmlparser

```
  String tagIdentifier=12;
 String sMyXML = "";

 sMyXML += "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";

 sMyXML += "<Tag>";
 sMyXML += "<Header>";
 sMyXML += "`<TagIdentifier></TagIdentifier>`";....
```

Here i want to use the String value tagIdentifier inside the XML

```
   String tagIdentifier=12;
```

How can i add this string inside the tags

```
<TagIdentifier>12</TagIdentifier>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sMyXML += "<TagIdentifier>" + tagIdentifier + "</TagIdentifier>";
```

but of course,

```
 String tagIdentifier = 12;
```

isn't valid in the first place.

Building up XML as strings is a headache though.  For all but the most trivial applications, I would recommend an XML library of which there are several - I'm using [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

you can build a `String` like mjg123 wrote by your self (in case of large XML string I recommend use `StringBuilder` rather than joining pure strings) or you can use API for building XML file. For example [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how general you want it to work. If you want it to be really generic you can use XMLParser, if you want it to work without much effort on your side you can

```
"<TagIdentifier>"+tagIdentifier+"</TagIdentifier>".
```

However in your code i would also change

```
String tagIdentifier=12;
```

to

```
String tagIdentifier = new String(new Integer(12));
```

The "new String" is pretty obvious; the "new Integer" is so that you are safe when you decide to parameterize "12" to something e.g. the user entered.